# How can I INSERT data into two tables simultaneously with only one sql script db2?

Tags: sql, db2-400

How would I insert into multiple tables with one sql script in db2

For example, insert a row into T1 `DOCK_DOOR` and then insert into T2 `DOCK_DOOR_LANE` multiple times based on the `dock_door_sysid` from the first table.

My first approach was the following. I was attempting to use a with with three inserts. on the other hand, doing to inserts on the second table is not and option if this can be automated with one insert.
thanks for any feedback

sql example

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO DBF1.DOCK_DOOR    (DOCK_DOOR_SYSID,DOOR_NUMBER,DOOR_NAME,DOCK_SYSID,DOOR_SEQ,ENCRYPTION_CODE,RFID_ENBLD_FLAG,LANES_COUNT,CMNT_TEXT,CREATE_TS,CREATE_USERID,UPDATE_TS,UPDATE_USERID,VER_NUMBER,ACTIVE_FLAG,STATUS_SYSID,DOOR_TYPE_SYSID) 
VALUES (nextval for DBF1.DOCK_DOOR_SEQ,'026','DOOR025',61,25,NULL,'N','2',NULL,current timestamp,'SQL_INSERT',current timestamp,'SQL_INSERT',0,NULL,1723,1142)
  RETURNING door_number,dock_door_sysid),
ins2 AS (
INSERT INTO SIT.DOCK_DOOR_lane (DOCK_DOOR_LANE_SYSID,DOOR_LANE_ID,DOCK_DOOR_SYSID,LANE_ID,CREATE_TS,CREATE_USERID,UPDATE_TS,UPDATE_USERID,VER_NUMBER) 
VALUES (nextval for DBF1.DOCK_DOOR_LANE_seq,door_number||''||'A',dock_door_sysid,'A',current timestamp},'SQL_INSERT',current timestamp,'SQL_INSERT',0)
  SELECT door_number,dock_door_sysid FROM DBF1.DOCK_DOOR
  RETURNING door_number,dock_door_sysid)
INSERT INTO DBF1.DOCK_DOOR_lane (DOCK_DOOR_LANE_SYSID,DOOR_LANE_ID,DOCK_DOOR_SYSID,LANE_ID,CREATE_TS,CREATE_USERID,UPDATE_TS,UPDATE_USERID,VER_NUMBER) 
VALUES (nextval for DBF1.DOCK_DOOR_LANE_seq,door_number||''||'B',dock_door_sysid,'B',current timestamp},'SQL_INSERT',current timestamp,'SQL_INSERT',0)
SELECT door_number,dock_door_sysid FROM DBF1.DOCK_DOOR;
```

Table 1 = `dock_door`

Table 2 = `Dock_door_lane`

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't think there is an equivalent.  In Oracle there is an INSERT FIRST and INSERT ALL.  In SQL Server there is an OUTPUT clause that lets you chain multiple operations.  Is there any reason you can't just wrap the INSERTs all in a transaction?

Comment: Thanks for feedback Cade. I was hoping that this might be possible with DB2, since inserting three consecutive inserts with SQL does solve this conundrum, but this is only helpful if only a few records need to be inserted. In a nutshell, I was hoping to avoid this without having to write a small program to automate the process.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a trigger on the `dock_door` table.

However, if you're on a recent,  version on IBM i.  You might be able to make use of [data change table reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafztabref.htm)

Your statement would look something like this

```
insert into dock_door_lane
  select <....>
    from final table (insert into dock_door <...>)
```

I'm not sure it will work, as this [article](https://www.itjungle.com/2015/01/20/fhg012015-story03/) indicates that at least at a couple of years ago DB2 for i didn't support the secondary insert required.

This old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221966/db2-storing-results-from-final-table-clause) also seems to confirm that at least at v7.1, the double insert isn't supported.

If I get a chance, I'll run a test on a 7.2 system Monday.

Comment: Running v7.2 TR 4, data change table reference isn't supported in the insert.  I get a an SQ20165 error.   I also don't see anything in the "What's new" section of v7.3 that would indicate the limitation was lifted.